# How to retain value returned from $http on browser back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have "search" button which returns array of object from rest service. I have popoulated the values to a table using `ng-repeat`. Now on clicking on of the colums my page navigates with the details to next page using `$routeprovider`.

My question is: when I click on browser back button, how to retain the values in the table?

This is my app.js:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/displayValues', {
        templateUrl: 'DisplayValues.html',
        controller: 'DisplayValuesController'
    })
    .when('/showDetails/:inputNumber', {
        templateUrl: 'ShowDetails.html',
        controller: 'DetailsController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/displayValues'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: By retain, do you mean not cause another http request?  If DisplayValuesController is using a service, then the service can use an in-memory cache

Comment: yes, may I know what do you mean by in-memory cache? I just wanted the table to be as it is on refresh also.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, used $cachefactory and its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Read about `reloadOnSearch` property on `$routeProvider`. If set to `false`, change in querystring values would not cause the controllers to reinitialized and hence they would maintain state (search results).

So if your navigation to detail page should navigate using querystring. To know that the view changed in that case you have to subscribe to `$routeUpdate` event. See $route documentation.

The other way is to cache the search result in a service and rebind when back to list page.

Answer (score 0):

You save state via services, which are singletons in AngularJs and accessible via dependency injection like everything else.

You can do something as simple as this (this is not ideal, just an example):

```
angular.module('myApp', []).service('valueService', function() {
    var currentValues;

    return{
      setValues: function(newValues) {
        currentValues = newValues;
      },
      getValues: function() {
        return currentValues;
      }
    }
});
```

Initially, your controller can call the service for data and if the value returned is undefined, do an XHR request to your server and store the value in the service.

You'd need additional logic and changes, but the basic idea is to cache the result in a service and retrieve that from your controller.